# Rank of subgroups of free groups

Tags: group-theory, covering-spaces, free-groups

I am familiar with Schreier's theorem which states that any subgroup H of a free group G is free, as well as with the formula
$$
\operatorname{rank} H - 1 = |G:H|(\operatorname{rank} G - 1)
$$

I have always encountered this formula with the caveat that the index |G:H| must be finite; however several professors have told me that in the case it is infinite it is also true and it just doesn't tell you anything interesting.

However, if $\operatorname{rank} G=n$ and $e_1,\dots,e_n$ is a basis of $G$, then for instance $H=\langle e_1,\dots,e_{n-1}\rangle$ is free of rank $n-1$ and the above formula cannot hold since $\dfrac{n-2}{n-1}$ is not an integer.

So it seems to me that subgroups whose rank is smaller than n must all have infinite index, and the formula then does need the finite index assumption after all. Is that right?

On the other hand, how does that translate into covering spaces of graphs? There should be for instance an infinite-fold covering of a two-circle bouquet whose fundamental group is infinite cyclic. How can that be? I think there's something off here...

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The index of $\langle e_1,\ldots,e_{n-1}\rangle$ in $G$ is infinite. The formula is nonsense when the index is infinite and the rank of $H$ and $G$ are both finite.

Comment: What is true is that the formula holds when the **rank** (of either $G$ or $H$) are infinite, but it just tells you that infinite equals infinite. But the formula requires $G$ finitely generated and either the rank of $H$ or the index to be (known to be) finite.

Comment: Minor comment: your first sentence is incomplete, I think it should say that $H$ is free.

Comment: I think your additional point about covering spaces of graphs belongs in a separate question.

Comment: Thank you both and don't worry about the covering space thing, I have just figured it out. Thank you very much.

Comment: Oh, oh, just in case someone reads this and has the same question: take the universal covering (aka the Cayley graph), remove two of the "main branches" labeled with the same generator, and replace them with a loop.

Comment: Maybe there is a missing "non-trivial, normal" attached to $H$ in what your professors told you? Non-trivial, normal subgroups of infinite index are not finitely generated, so here we again just have $\infty=\infty$.